# How can I track the ActivityManager loading time of my app?

Tags: android, performance, android-lifecycle, android-activitymanager

I would like to track how much time take my app to start, but I would like to track this specific info defined here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time 
In order to have better graphics about it and add custom info to it. 
What I have tried?

I have tried to add a timer between `onCreate` method and `onResume` but the time obtained is the half of the time tracked by the system "Activity Manager: Displayed"

What can I do to have those values programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should count the time between `Application.onCreate()` to end of `Activity.onCreate()` to get the cold startup time. Please read [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time) for more info on this.

Let me explain. In your application class:

```
class YourApplication: Application() {

public static long starttime = 0;

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
    starttime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
}
}
```

In your launcher activity class, upon completion of onCreate method:

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
       long timeelapsed = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - YourApplication.starttime);
     Log.i("TEST", "your time : "+ timeelapsed)
    }

}
```

Comment: should I "stop" the timer at the begining of "onCreate" method ?  , I am testing it to see what I get.

Comment: This dont worked as the same way , i get 1500 ms vs 2s659ms . I tried to measure until "onResume" with the next result 1669 ms

Comment: Isn't it better to check the elapsed time in Acitivity.onResume() instead? That's when the UI is rendered and active.

Comment: that is right, but, the diference is at least 1 second! ... I know the doc says how it is measured, but, the result obtained is diferent